# Submit button in form doesn't work with Iscroll

Tags: javascript, iscroll

i use Iscroll 5, everything is working as i want except one thing. 
I can't click on a submit button in a form, nothing happens.

This is my code, i tried many things but i don't know how can i fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scroll;
function loaded() {
        scroll = new IScroll('#contenu', {
        tap:true,
        desktopCompatibility: true,
        scrollbars: false,
        interactiveScrollbars: true,
        freeScroll: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        momentum: false,
        mouseWheel: true,
        click: true,
        useTransform: false,
            onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                var target = e.target;
                while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;    
                if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'  && target.tagName != 'BUTTON') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }   

            }
    });
}

//disables browser mouse scrolling
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
}

function wheel(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dude your are my hero your fix work well but I have made it some improvement because the default handler was different :)

So I replace normal click event on iscroll line 1565

```
case 'click':
            if ( !e._constructed ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            break;
```

by this line and now I have no problem my send and reset input work well ty dude !

```
case 'click':
        if ( !e._constructed ) {
        if ( !e._constructed && target.type != "submit") {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
        }
        break;
```

this is working well  on my ipad Android phone and chrome Firefox not tested on IE, but the inspector show me an error he say that target is not define?

Someone have an idea for fixing that :p?

ps for the author : You must put click to false in your iscroll déclaration else you will have a bug and people cant write correcty text in input type text !

Comment: target.type just throws an error, do
if(e.target.type == "submit"){return;}
instead

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, i could help someone,

```
case 'click':
            if ( !e._constructed ) {
            if ( !e._constructed && target.type != "submit") {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            }
```

in iscroll.js.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line of code from `iscroll5` js file

```
if ( !e._constructed ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

with

```
if ( !e._constructed && e.target.type != 'submit' ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue. Other answers did not fix my issue.

Fixed it with removing the click option `click: true` altogether.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll):

> options.click
>
> To override the native scrolling iScroll has to inhibit some default
>   browser behaviors, such as mouse clicks. If you want your application
>   to respond to the click event you have to explicitly set this option
>   to true. **Please note that it is suggested to use the custom tap event
>   instead (see below).**
>
> Default: false